# Catching timeout errors with ruby mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have a mechanize function to log me out of a site but on very rare occasions it times me out. The function involves going to a specific page, and then clicking on a logout button. On the occasional that mechanize suffers a timeout when either going to the logout page or clicking the logout button the code crashes. So I put in a small rescue and it seems to be working as seen below the first piece of code.

```
def logmeout(agent)
  page = agent.get('http://www.example.com/')
  agent.click(page.link_with(:text => /Log Out/i))
end
```

Logmeout with rescue:

```
def logmeout(agent)
  begin
  page = agent.get('http://www.example.com/')
  agent.click(page.link_with(:text => /Log Out/i))
  rescue Timeout::Error 
    puts "Timeout!"
    retry
  end
end
```

Assuming I understand rescue correctly, it will do both actions over even if just the clicking timed out, so in the effort to be efficient I am was wondering if I could use a proc in this situation and pass it a code block. Would something like this work:

```
def trythreetimes
  tries = 0
  begin
  yield
  rescue
    tries += 1
    puts "Trying again!"
    retry if tries <= 3
  end
end

def logmeout(agent)
  trythreetimes {page = agent.get('http://www.example.com/')}
  trythreetimes {agent.click(page.link_with(:text => /Log Out/i))}
end
```

Note in my trythreetimes function I left it as generic rescue so the function would be more re-usable.

Thanks so much for any help anyone can provide, I realize there are a couple different questions in here but they are all things I am trying to learn!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of retrying some timeouts on some mechanize requests I think you'd better set [`Mechanize::HTTP::Agent::read_timeout`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/HTTP/Agent.html#read_timeout=) attribute to a reasonable amount of seconds like 2 or 5, anyway one that prevent timeouts errors for this request.

Then, it seem's that your log out procedure only required access to a simple HTTP GET request. I mean there is no form to fill in so no HTTP POST request.
So if I were you, I would prefere inspected the page source code (Ctrl+U with Firefox or Chrome) in order to identify the link which is reached by your `agent.click(page.link_with(:text => /Log Out/i))`
It should be faster because these type of pages are usually blank and Mechanize will not have to load a full html web page in memory.

Here is the code I would prefer use :

```
def logmeout(agent)
  begin
  agent.read_timeout=2  #set the agent time out
  page = agent.get('http://www.example.com/logout_url.php')
  agent.history.pop()   #delete this request in the history
  rescue Timeout::Error 
    puts "Timeout!"
    puts "read_timeout attribute is set to #{agent.read_timeout}s" if !agent.read_timeout.nil?
    #retry      #retry is no more needed
  end
end
```

but you can use your retry function too :

```
def trythreetimes
  tries = 0
  begin
  yield
  rescue Exception => e  
  tries += 1
  puts "Error: #{e.message}"
  puts "Trying again!" if tries <= 3
  retry if tries <= 3
  puts "No more attempt!"
  end
end

def logmeout(agent)
  trythreetimes do
  agent.read_timeout=2  #set the agent time out
  page = agent.get('http://www.example.com/logout_url.php')
  agent.history.pop()       #delete this request in the history
  end
end
```

hope it helps ! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your preferred code is assuming you found the correct link through the source code?

Comment: Well, it's not really difficult to find a link inside an HTML source. I prefer this solution because of the time & memory needed. but you can use your solution with the [`read_timeout`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/HTTP/Agent.html#read_timeout=) set. It's a good idea if you use it for multiple domains. Just edit my second peace of code and change it to access the main page and to click on the link if you prefer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't answer your question in fact. Yes it's assuming you found the correct link through the source code...

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on this and for making me aware of read_timeout!

Answer (score 0):

Using mechanize 1.0.0 I got this problem from a different source of error.

In my case I was blocked by proxy and then SSL.  This worked for me:

```
ag = Mechanize.new
ag.set_proxy('yourproxy', yourport)
ag.agent.http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
ag.get( url )
```